# Is it possible to send multiple email attachments with zend_mail?

Tags: zend-framework, sendmail, zend-mail

I found several examples of sending a single email attachment using zend_mail.  But I cannot figure out how to send multiple attachments.  Can someone share how to do this if it is possible. I have sendmail installed on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible to send more than one attachment in a `Zend_Mail_Message`.

Depending on what method you use for creating attachments, just call `$mail->createAttachment()` once per attachment, or create all of your attachments as `Zend_Mime_Part` objects and call `$mail->addAttachment($part)` once for each attachment.

See [Zend Mail Attachments](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.attachments.html) for examples.  Just repeat the example once for each file you want to attach.

Comment: how to send multiple attachments in zend framework - 3 version? Please share any suggestion. Thanks.